# How to remove internal shadow of React Native StackNavigator when using safeAreaView together

Tags: react-native, shadow, iphone-x

I'm using `import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';` for new iPhone X development, but I'm getting a boring shadow inside the area. How can I remove it?

[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYy5M.png)

```
// Code

import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
 ...
</SafeAreaView>


// Style
safeArea: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: colors.background,
},
```

**UPDATE:** I figured out that's probably some kind of conflict with the StackNavigator ( with headerMode: 'none'). When I don't have safeAreaView in my code, stack hide the header correctly.

**UPDATE 2:** @Julien Malige, that's the point I am. Tks
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `shadowOpacity` to `0` in the `safeArea` style object?

Comment: I'll try!, but I think my main problem after fight with that, is the stackNavigator... I set it to headerMode: 'none'. When I try it without safeAreaView, everything goes fine, but when safeAreaView is there, the headerMode: 'none' stops hide the header.

Comment: Nothing changed with shadowOpacity on SafeAreaView

Comment: Unrelated to the question: how did you do the `backgroundColor: colors.background,` thing?

Comment: Nevermind found it... https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-meteor-boilerplate/blob/master/RNApp/app/config/styles.js

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved the problem using a React Navigation property:

> **cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' }**

```
const Routes = StackNavigator({
  Identify: { screen: IdentifyRoutes },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' },
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this puzzled me for days :) !

Comment: yeah! clean way to do it